# Differences between SWT/JFCE in Linux and OS X

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am running in the following:

I have an eclipse plugin(Luna/JVM 1.8) that presents some information to the user in a `CTabItem`. In this `CTabItem`, I have a class that updates a `TextViewer`'s widget contents using `asyncExec(....)`.

A brute force approach of `getTextWidget().append(String)` process the `String[]` inside the UI/`asyncExec()`;

This logic has worked reliably in OS X (El Capitan). I am using linux (openSuse Leap) now and the updates rarely show up in the `TextViewer`. I have checked and the runnable inside the `asyncExec(...)` gets called.

The rest of the UI elements work normally in both OSs.

What do I need to change or am I missing? This seems more due to my lack of understanding of cross-platform SWT than anything else.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to show us some code.

Comment: Let me get back to you on that I got tangled up on something else now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I made 2 simple changes:

Instead of calling `getTextWidget().append(String)` I am using a `StringBuilder` and making just one call to `getTextWidget().append(String)`.

After this I call `refresh()`.

These two did the trick.